# Proving that applicative functors compose

Tags: usage, tactic, category-theory

For simplicity, here an applicative functor means (in a proof assistant based on dependent type theory) the Haskellian applicative functor, bundled with its equational laws.

This I can of course brute force in any proof assistant. Nevertheless, streamlining such a proof is an interesting challenge. The definition for `pure` and `<*>` is easy, as can be copied off any Haskell library. The equational reasoning however is very very tedious, which anyone would agree if they were to write it down on paper.

One thing to note is that you can mechanically prove all four laws by deciding on a set of appropriate rewriting directions, and apply laws whenever you can. I would like to know how this is actually carried out in a tactic-based approach, and also whether this strategy can be used in non-tactic based proofs. And if unfortunately not, what other techniques can be used to reduce the tedium?

Comment: I think this is the Lean version for reference: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/control/applicative.html#functor.comp.is_lawful_applicative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how this is actually carried out in a tactic-based approach

The theorem [`functor.comp.is_lawful_applicative`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/control/applicative.html#functor.comp.is_lawful_applicative) in Lean's `mathlib` library is what you are looking for:

```
@[protected, instance]
def functor.comp.is_lawful_applicative
  {F : Type u → Type w} {G : Type v → Type u}
  [applicative F] [applicative G]
  [is_lawful_applicative F] [is_lawful_applicative G] :
is_lawful_applicative (functor.comp F G)
```

I think [the proof](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/ed8330608eb184bd3a8b7e877f118bfe34751e9a/src/control/applicative.lean#L90) basically follows the brute force approah you had in mind, but here are a few comments:

- The `mathlib` control library is very systematic, proving results for functors, applicative functors, monads, etc (both the lawful and non-lawful versions).  This breaks up the work and likely helps to keep track of everything.
- The `mathlib` definition of a lawful applicative functor is a class (a structure which can be used as a type class):

  ```
  class is_lawful_applicative (f : Type u → Type v) [applicative f] extends is_lawful_functor f : Prop :=
  (seq_left_eq  : ∀ {α β : Type u} (a : f α) (b : f β), a <* b = const β <$> a <*> b . control_laws_tac)
  (seq_right_eq : ∀ {α β : Type u} (a : f α) (b : f β), a *> b = const α id <$> a <*> b . control_laws_tac)
  -- applicative laws
  (pure_seq_eq_map : ∀ {α β : Type u} (g : α → β) (x : f α), pure g <*> x = g <$> x)
  (map_pure        : ∀ {α β : Type u} (g : α → β) (x : α), g <$> (pure x : f α) = pure (g x))
  (seq_pure        : ∀ {α β : Type u} (g : f (α → β)) (x : α), g <*> pure x = (λ g : α → β, g x) <$> g)
  (seq_assoc       : ∀ {α β γ : Type u} (x : f α) (g : f (α → β)) (h : f (β → γ)), h <*> (g <*> x) = (@comp α β γ <$> h) <*> g <*> x)
  -- default functor law
  (comp_map := begin intros; simp [(pure_seq_eq_map _ _).symm, seq_assoc, map_pure, seq_pure] end)
  ```
- I think the control library is one of the major successes of Lean's type class system.  Many facts about instances of say applicative functors (such as that the composition of two lawful applicative functors like `option` and `list` are still lawful) is automatically derived by the type class system.
- Further, Lean provides some automation to make it easier to show that an applicative functor is lawful.  For example, the first two fields `seq_left_eq` and `seq_right_eq` are automatically derived by default using the tactic `control_laws_tac` which is just a follow-your-nose sequence of steps: ``` whnf_target >> intros >> to_expr ``(rfl) >>= exact ```.
- [The proof](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/ed8330608eb184bd3a8b7e877f118bfe34751e9a/src/control/applicative.lean#L90) of [`functor.comp.is_lawful_applicative`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/control/applicative.html#functor.comp.is_lawful_applicative) is based on a number of lemmas.  The lemma proof are short, often mostly relying on the `simp` tactic and various rewrite lemmas.  Some of these rewrite rules are annotated with the label `functor_norm` so one can just do, e.g. `simp [applicative.pure_seq_eq_map'] with functor_norm` to apply them during simplification.
- `mathlib` has a separate [category theory library](https://leanprover-community.github.io/theories/category_theory.html) which redefines the same objects, like [functor](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/category_theory/functor/basic.html#category_theory.functor) and [monad](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/category_theory/monad/basic.html#category_theory.monad), but in the usual category theoretic manner (which is more useful for doing mathematics).  For that library, I heard they developed the [`tidy` tactic](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#tidy) to do a lot of the tedious follow-your-nose sort of reasoning.  (The `tidy` tactic tries a bunch of common tactics, like `intros` and `simp`, in sequence until one of them works.  It then applies it and repeat the process, without ever backtracking.)